# PDO posting to different tables depending on username

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, pdo

Very new to all of this (as most are when asking questions)..

What i am trying to achieve: (ive changed table names to make it easier to read)

Striped down i have three tables: users, table1, table2 in my DB.

I have a pdo login in scrip that works fine, and also displays certain user info in a profile page.

(i should add that ive built all of this through tutorials and snippets and meshed them together myself, so while i can vaguely read code and understand it, my ability to actually write it is virtually non existent.. but we all have to start from somewhere).

What i want to do is have a form submit to a different table depending on the user login.

I can get the form to submit and update the table IF i specify the exact table name, but i need this to be dependant on the username (if that makes sense).

Maybe a little background on what im trying to build..

I work for a small pub company and am trying to create an online cash sheet where the manager logs in fills in the form and automatically posted over to us..

I have a self calculating form (javascript for the calculations) that will post the user input to the DB (it also emails a pdf via dompdf but i have removed this for now as its the sunnmission to the database i nee to focus on)

The sheet and the dompdf all works there are no problems here (even if my code may not be optimal).

We have 13 sites, and rather than having 13 individual pages i would like to load the sites info depending on the login, as i said i have a login that works and differentiates between the users, the problem im having is getting the form to submit to a particular table depending on that login..

In the users table i have a column called 'sheet_upload' this contains the table name for that user.

It should be noted that i am creating all the logins for the sites, so i am in complete control of anything that is input to the users table.

What is the best way for me to achieve what im looking for..

would it be using an elseif statement, or switch, or having the 'sheet_upload' passed to a variable on login and then referenced on 'INSERT INTO' (as ive tried to do below), or storing the table name in a session..

I apologise for this being so vague, but ive been looking for days now and im no closer so thought i would at least throw a question out there and see if anyone can point me in the right direction..

the code i have for inserting the form info so far is as below: (ive stripped out a lot of fields as they are irrelevant and just take up space).

As you can see in the code im currently trying to reference the 'sheet upload' in the users table..

Absolutely any direction here will be a help..

```
$config = array(
'host'      => '',
'username'  => '',
'password'  => '',
'dbname'    => ''
);

try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['dbname'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($_POST['weekEnding'])) {
$weekending = $_POST['weekEnding'];
$monW = $_POST['monW']; $monD = $_POST['monD'];$tueW = $_POST['tueW'];$tueD = $_POST['tueD'];$wedW = $_POST['wedW']; 
$wedD = $_POST['wedD'];$thuW = $_POST['thuW']; $thuD = $_POST['thuD'];$friW = $_POST['friW']; $friD = $_POST['friD'];
$satW = $_POST['satW'];$satD = $_POST['satD'];$sunW = $_POST['sunW'];$sunD = $_POST['sunD'];$weeklyZTotals = $_POST['weeklyZ'];



$tablename   = $_GET['sheet_upload'];




$q = "INSERT INTO " . $tablename . "(
weekending, monW, monD, tueW, tueD, wedW, wedD, thuW, thuD, friW, friD, satW, satD, sunW, sunD, weeklyZTotals,
);";


$query = $db->prepare($q);


$results = $query->execute(array(
":weekending" => $weekending,":monW" => $monW,":monD" => $monD,":tueW" => $tueW, ":tueD" => $tueD,":wedW" => $wedW, 
":wedD" => $wedD,":thuW" => $thuW, ":thuD" => $thuD,":friW" => $friW, ":friD" => $friD,":satW" => $satW, ":satD" => $satD,
":sunW" => $sunW, ":sunD" => $sunD,":weeklyZTotals" => $weeklyZTotals       
));


}
```

Comment: You could make use of [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) using the user's `id` number for example, and then pass it on to your `$tablename` such as `$tablename=$_SESSION['id']` or vice-versa which will save you a lot of coding. That's what I use and it works very well.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i can see how i can pass the session 'id' but i cant see how that links to the table name in my DB... Sorry if this is such a stupid question..